# lock for a whole class in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, synchronized

I have a pretty simple question that I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction on. I'm a java developer trying to figure out the correct objective C approach to a global lock. I have a class which is instantiated in several place. Each instance reads and writes to a single common file. As such, I need to make sure all method calls in this class are atomic. In java this would be done as follows:

```
static Object lock

public void writeToFile(){
    synchronized(lock){
      //thread safe code goes here
    }
}
```

The static identifier would mean that the lock object is shared across all instances and would as such be threadsafe. Unfortunately since iOS doesn't have class variables in the same way, I'm not sure what the best way to achieve this functionality is.

Comment: note: I have tried doing @synchronized(self.class) and nothing has complained, but I am not 100% sure that this is the right way to approach this?

Comment: `@synchronized(self.class)` will indeed work and block all objects of that class. If you only meant to lock this instance, use `@synchronized(self)` instead. If you need non-blocking locks, check out the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396945/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-is-being-synchronized/17399427#17399427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is a simple global lock, look at NSLock.

eg:

```
static NSLock * myGlobalLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

if ([myGlobalLock tryLock]) {
    // do something
    [myGlobalLock unlock];
}
else {
    // couldn't acquire lock
}
```

However, this is going to incur a performance penalty because it requires a kernel call.  If you want to serialize access to a resource, using Grand Central Dispatch and a private queue is going to perform much better--these are scheduled without requiring a kernel interrupt.

eg:

```
// alloc a dispatch queue for controlling access to your shared resource
static dispatch_queue_t mySharedResourceQueue = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    mySharedResourceQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myidentifier.MySharedResourceQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL); // pick a unique identifier
});
// don't forget to call dispatch_release() to clean up your queue when done with it!

// to serialize access to your shared resource and block the current thread...
dispatch_sync(mySharedResourceQueue, ^{
    // access my shared resource
});

// or to access it asynchronously, w/o blocking the current thread...
dispatch_async(mySharedResourceQueue, ^{
    // access my shared resource
});
```

Dispatch queues are highly awesome things and if you're getting in to iOS development you should learn how to use them in order to make apps with great performance.

There are different types of locks besides NSLock too.  Read up on synchronization in the Threaded Programming reference for more info...

Threaded Programming reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i

NSLock reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Grand Central Dispatch reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: That queue should be created with the explicit DISPATCH_.._SERIAL option.

Comment: From Apple's docs: "By default, queues created with dispatch_queue_create() wait for the previously dequeued block to complete before dequeuing the next block. This FIFO completion behavior is sometimes simply described as a "serial queue.""

Comment: Sure -- but that doesn't mean you shouldn't be explicit in your code.   The more explicit concurrency code is, the easier it is for someone new (including yourself six months from now ;) to maintain it in the future.   Obviously, that is a default behavior that can't be changed, but why make future maintainers look up that behavior?